# Flatpickr: Adding dropdown to change year

Tags: jquery, flatpickr

I am using [Flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) for my calendar needs. It provides an input field with arrows to change the year.

I need to have a dropdown inside the calendar so that I can select a year from that dropdown and the calendar points to that year subsequently.

I have given a special class `.birthDate` to the calendar element dynamically. I have added a dropdown to the calendar dynamically, like so:

```
var currYear = new Date().getFullYear()

var yearOptions = "";

for(var i =  1960; i <= currYear; i++) {
    var option = "<option value = " +  i + ">" + i + "</option>";
    yearOptions += option;
}

var yearDropdown = "<select class=\"year-dropdown\">" + yearOptions + "</select>";
 $(".birthDate .flatpickr-current-month").append(yearDropdown);
```

The problem is, nothing happens when I click it. My guess is there's some `preventDefault` method that prevents any click from causing any action. Yet when I add a console statement on click of the dropdown, it appears on the console.

So my question is how do i open the dropdown on click of it. Please find an example of the issue [here](https://codepen.io/binarytrance/pen/WKoNVJ).

Answer (score 6):

if anyone is interested in adding a year dropdown select option to Flatpickr, here is my solution

```
    // plugin js file
    /**
 * Flatpickr Year Select Plugin.
 * @author Labi Romabravo
 */

/**
 *
 * @returns {Function}
 */
const yearDropdownPlugin = function (pluginConfig) {
    var defaultConfig = {
        text: '',
        theme: "light",
        date: new Date(),
        yearStart: 100,
        yearEnd: 2,

    };

    var config = {};
    for (var key in defaultConfig) {
        config[key] = pluginConfig && pluginConfig[key] !== undefined ? pluginConfig[key] : defaultConfig[key];
    }

    var getYear = function (value) {
        var date = value.split("/");
        return parseInt(date[2], 10);
    }

    var currYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    var selectedYear = getYear(config.date);

    var yearDropdown = document.createElement("select");

    var createSelectElement = function (year) {
        var start = new Date().getFullYear() - config.yearStart;
        var end = currYear + config.yearEnd;

        for (var i = end; i >= start; i--) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = i;
            option.text = i;
            yearDropdown.appendChild(option);
        }
        yearDropdown.value = selectedYear;
    };

    return function (fp) {
        fp.yearSelectContainer = fp._createElement(
            "div",
            "flatpickr-year-select " + config.theme + "Theme",
            config.text
        );

        fp.yearSelectContainer.tabIndex = -1;
        createSelectElement(selectedYear);
        yearDropdown.addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
            var year = evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex].value;
            fp.changeYear(year);
        });

        fp.yearSelectContainer.append(yearDropdown);

        return {
            onReady: function onReady() {
                var name = fp.monthNav.className;               
                const yearInputCollection = fp.calendarContainer.getElementsByClassName(name);
                const el = yearInputCollection[0];
                el.parentNode.insertBefore(fp.yearSelectContainer, el.parentNode.firstChild);
            }
        };
    };
}

export default yearDropdownPlugin
// if (typeof module !== "undefined")
//     module.exports = yearDropdownPlugin;
```

Usage

```
import yearDropdownPlugin from "@/utils/year_flatpickr_plugin";
var input = document.querySelector("#" + this.containerId);

  this.datepicker = flatpickr(input, {
    plugins: [
      new yearDropdownPlugin({
        date: this.value,
        yearStart: this.yearStart,
        yearEnd: this.yearEnd
      })
    ],
    wrap: true,
    enableTime: false,
    dateFormat: "d/m/Y",
    minDate: this.min
    //mode: "range"
  });
```

Css

```
.flatpickr-current-month .numInputWrapper {
    display: none;
}
.flatpickr-current-month span.cur-month {
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 85px;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: right;
}
.flatpickr-current-month {
    width: 100px;
}
.flatpickr-year-select {
    background-color:#052f66;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 70px;
    width: 100px;


}
.flatpickr-year-select select{
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    outline: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #747a80;
    border: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Final output
[image: dropdown preview]

Comment: great work, but how to use it with react, here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/date-range-react-bprul?file=/src/FlatPicker.js

Comment: throws me an error: "expects function declaration". Even when I put plugin into the same file where I insert it into plugin prop, still throw this error.

Comment: For what it's worth, I made a [TypeScript version of this](https://gist.github.com/ZachSaucier/ec6f58e49082c27eaae240786bc82997) (with some lazy typing for the flatpickr instance - you could [add the full type](https://gist.github.com/kunjee17/761f3ffeabd6c9abc04e89a148b8a67c) if you'd like)

Answer (score 5):

Got here after our client request to change year picker to something more comfortable. Thanks to a guy above providing with some links to flatpickr plugin options.

Here is my solution if anybody still needs it.
First off all, we have a setting script in html page (later called using wicket). It creates a flatpickr instance and binds it to an html element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        const FLATPICKR_CUSTOM_YEAR_SELECT = 'flatpickr-custom-year-select';
        const initDatePicker = function (inputId) {
            $("#" + inputId).flatpickr({
                dateFormat: "d/m/Y",
                minDate: "01.01.1900",
                maxDate: "01.01.2100",
                allowInput: true,
                onChange: function () {
                    $("#" + inputId).blur();
                }
            })
        };
</script>
```

What I did is just added some additional code in order to insert a select tag instead of the existing element and provide with event processing in order to follow value change in the custom select and pass it to a native element.
In orReady event native year picker gets hidden, select element gets created and onChange event implemented where selected value is passed to a native year element. onMonthChange is needed in order to change year value when clicking on side arrows (changing month).
So now it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        const FLATPICKR_CUSTOM_YEAR_SELECT = 'flatpickr-custom-year-select';
        const initDatePicker = function (inputId) {
            $("#" + inputId).flatpickr({
                dateFormat: "d/m/Y",
                minDate: "01.01.1900",
                maxDate: "01.01.2100",
                allowInput: true,
                onChange: function () {
                    $("#" + inputId).blur();
                },
               //here what was added
                onReady: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
                    const flatpickrYearElement = instance.currentYearElement;

                    const children = flatpickrYearElement.parentElement.children;
                    for (let i in children) {
                        if (children.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                            children[i].style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    }

                    const yearSelect = document.createElement('select');
                    const minYear = new Date(instance.config._minDate).getFullYear();
                    const maxYear = new Date(instance.config._maxDate).getFullYear();
                    for (let i = minYear; i < maxYear; i++) {
                        const option = document.createElement('option');
                        option.value = '' + i;
                        option.text = '' + i;
                        yearSelect.appendChild(option);
                    }
                    yearSelect.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
                        flatpickrYearElement.value = event.target['value'];
                        instance.currentYear = parseInt(event.target['value']);
                        instance.redraw();
                    });

                    yearSelect.className = 'flatpickr-monthDropdown-months';
                    yearSelect.id = FLATPICKR_CUSTOM_YEAR_SELECT;
                    yearSelect.value = instance.currentYearElement.value;

                    flatpickrYearElement.parentElement.appendChild(yearSelect);
                },
                onMonthChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
                    document.getElementById(FLATPICKR_CUSTOM_YEAR_SELECT).value = '' + instance.currentYear;
                }
            })
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the source, flatpickr is binding events to its own events handlers.
[image: Screenshot of where the events are bound]

The click made is actually handled in **documentClick** function and I guess that's why the dropdown is not opening. 
Also, to create a dropdown year select, try writing a flatpickr plugin (check https://flatpickr.js.org/plugins/). 
There is also a closed ticket where this was raised as a request (https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/issues/965). You can check and follow up on it.